Added test fails with and causes cascading "_jestWorker(...).messageParent is not a function" exceptions
A recently added unit test fails with a TypeError "_jestWorker(...).messageParent is not a function" and it causes many subsequent tests to fail with the same error.
If I remove the one unit test, everything works. Running with max-workers 1 or detect open handles succeeds as well.
The tests in question are asynchronous and are doing some fairly intricate mocks of fetch and some file system operations, so my initial assumption was that I was leaking something somewhere, but I haven't been able to find it if I am.
I caught the exception in the debugger and it looks like the failure message is 'test-start' for a test adjacent to the test whose addition caused the errors to start occuring, which makes me wonder if the test itself is running on an unexpected thread (i.e. a worker).
Typescript test running in node in a monorepo, fwiw.
Stack trace below:
Exception has occurred: TypeError: (0 , _jestWorker(...).messageParent) is not a function
  at sendMessageToJest ({omitted}/common/temp/node_modules/.pnpm/jest-runner@29.7.0/node_modules/jest-runner/build/testWorker.js:102:35)
    at {omitted}/node_modules/.pnpm/jest-circus@29.7.0/node_modules/jest-circus/build/testCaseReportHandler.js:19:7
    at dispatch ({omitted}/common/temp/node_modules/.pnpm/jest-circus@29.7.0/node_modules/jest-circus/build/state.js:67:11)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at _runTest ({omitted}/common/temp/node_modules/.pnpm/jest-circus@29.7.0/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:235:3)
    at _runTestsForDescribeBlock ({omitted}/common/temp/node_modules/.pnpm/jest-circus@29.7.0/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:126:9)
    at _runTestsForDescribeBlock ({omitted}/common/temp/node_modules/.pnpm/jest-circus@29.7.0/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:121:9)
    at _runTestsForDescribeBlock ({omitted}/common/temp/node_modules/.pnpm/jest-circus@29.7.0/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:121:9)
    at run ({omitted}/common/temp/node_modules/.pnpm/jest-circus@29.7.0/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:71:3)
    at runAndTransformResultsToJestFormat ({omitted}/common/temp/node_modules/.pnpm/jest-circus@29.7.0/node_modules/jest-circus/build/legacy-code-todo-rewrite/jestAdapterInit.js:122:21)
    at jestAdapter ({omitted}/common/temp/node_modules/.pnpm/jest-circus@29.7.0/node_modules/jest-circus/build/legacy-code-todo-rewrite/jestAdapter.js:79:19)
    at runTestInternal ({omitted}/common/temp/node_modules/.pnpm/jest-runner@29.7.0/node_modules/jest-runner/build/runTest.js:367:16)
    at runTest ({omitted}/common/temp/node_modules/.pnpm/jest-runner@29.7.0/node_modules/jest-runner/build/runTest.js:444:34)
    at Object.worker ({omitted}/common/temp/node_modules/.pnpm/jest-runner@29.7.0/node_modules/jest-runner/build/testWorker.js:106:12)

I was expecting my tests to pass or fail, not fail to load.  I was really not expecting an added unit test in one module to cause subsequent modules to fail
What I tried:

setting max-workers to 1 makes everything pass
setting detect-open-handles makes everything pass
removing that single last unit test makes everything pass
no amount of tinkering with that last unit tests makes things pass, which makes me suggest something in my setup code

I can't share the code, unfortunately and haven't been able to come up with a repro of any kind, never mind one I can share.
Happy to debug further myself but I seem to be getting deeper into the guts of jest than I've been to date, so I'm not even sure where to start.  Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

A few more observations:

I now see the exception if I run jest without the added test, but focused with -t on the tests from the module that makes things go haywire
adding more tests, reordering things, adding delays etc. all seem to have no effect.  If I have a single test in the describe it works, if I have more it fails.
I thought maybe there from my test code or mock was confusing things, but I've run through a few times debugging caught exceptions and I haven't seen any.

